# Java Time period in decimal number of months

Tags: java, date

**Can we get difference between two dates in decimal value.**

From Date - 2021-08-01

To Date - 2021-08-16

Difference - 0.5

Logic should support any date.

Eg:-
Difference between 2021-07-12 and 2021-08-5

Comment: convert both the dates to unix timestamps, and you can do the rest of the math yourself 

Comment: @SamridhTuladhar I thought of a very generic way to support any date. As example difference between 2021-07-12 and 2021-08-5

Comment: Since a "month" is a standard length (31, 30, 29, 28 days), what does half a month mean?  15.75, 15, 14.5, 14 days??

Comment: 'Decimal'? Do you mean 'real'? 'With a fractional component'?

Comment: August is 31 days long, so 15 days of august is `15/31 = 0.48387`, not `0.5`.

Comment: @Abra `ChronoUnit.MONTHS` returns `long`, not `double`

Comment: @SamridhTuladhar Not possible. We’d need both a time zone and a time of day to convert to Unix timestamps. It’s also very low-level.

Answer (score 1):

As you've cleared your expected value and business in the comments, I'm replacing my old answer with this:

You can use `LocalDateTime` to various operations from day count to month identification and so on. And the following code exactly does what you want, even if the dates are ranging in different months:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    double res = 0;
    LocalDate localDate1 = LocalDate.parse("2021-08-01");
    LocalDate localDate2 = LocalDate.parse("2021-08-16");

    if (localDate1.getMonthValue() == localDate2.getMonthValue()) {
        Period period = Period.between(localDate1, localDate2.plusDays(1));
        long days = period.getDays();
        res = (double) days / localDate1.lengthOfMonth();
    } else {
        int daysLeftInPrevMonth = localDate1.lengthOfMonth() - localDate1.getDayOfMonth();
        int diffOfMonths = localDate2.getMonthValue() - localDate1.getMonthValue() - 1;
        int daysLeftInNextMonth = localDate2.getDayOfMonth();
        res = (double) daysLeftInPrevMonth / localDate1.lengthOfMonth() + diffOfMonths
                + (double) daysLeftInNextMonth / localDate2.lengthOfMonth();

    }

    Double finalResult = BigDecimal.valueOf(res)
            .setScale(1, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP).doubleValue();
    System.out.println(finalResult);

}
```

**Note:** Keep in mind that the first date should be smaller than the second one.

Comment: So i'll have to divide by days per each month. This is very cumbersome. As example if i want to get the difference between 2021-07-12 and 2021-08-5

Comment: that's what I've said, You haven't made that clear what are you exactly expecting and on which basis. What type of difference are you expecting? If you do not have a baseline, you can make it a plain 30 days = 1 month, if your business requirement supports that

Comment: I've clearly explained what i expect. Simply the month difference between two dates without rounding it. Above dates i've given as an example. So our logic should support any dates

Comment: Sir you didn't get my point, what's your expected answer on such dates spanning between months? For example, `2021-06-11` and `2021-07-28`? You can have difference in days without question, but what will be the expected output in this case as you're calculating the difference in terms of months?

Comment: ((2021-06-30) - (2021-06-11)  / 30 ) + (28) / (31)

This is the math behind this

Comment: Now that makes sense, please update your question with this example too. I'm updating my answer soon.

Comment: Anything modern should be using the `java.time` classes, which also make this much easier to deal with.

Comment: @user3025404, I've updated my answer with the way you expected. This will give what you want.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- I've updated my answer with `LocalDate`, hope that's okay enough.

Comment: @user3025404 I am repeating what devReddit said: please update *your question* with the information that you have given in the comments (and i will retract my downvote). Stack Overflow is a long-term repository of questions and answers, much like an encyclopedia, so we need the questions to be good and clear for people to find their way here. Thank you.